# mod_rewrite: Demystifying RewriteBase (once and for all)

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I keep seeing this (for neatness, I'm omitting `IfModule` and `RewriteEngine` directives):

```
RewriteBase /somedir/                  #1
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]         #2
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    #3
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    #4
RewriteRule . /somedir/index.php [L]   #5
```

From the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) (and my experience):

> When using the rewrite engine in .htaccess files the per-directory
>   prefix [...] is automatically removed for the RewriteRule pattern
>   matching and automatically added after any ***relative* (not starting
>   with a slash or protocol name) substitution** encounters the end of a
>   rule set. See the RewriteBase directive for more information regarding
>   what prefix will be added back to ***relative* substitutions**.

Now, line #5 above **is NOT** a *relative* substitution (note the leading slash), so line #1 has no effect, since no prefix is added for "absolute" substitutions.
Then my question is, isn't there redundancy between directive #1 and part of #5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Then my question is, isn't there redundancy between directive #1 and part of #5?

No it is not a redundancy actually. It is only because you're using absolute URL here which tell `mod_rewrite` engine to use absolute URL in rewrite instead of relative one.

If your 5th line becomes:

```
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Then `RewriteBase` will be in effect and will be used to rewrite the URI as: `/somedir/index.php`

**Main advantage** of using `RewriteBase` is that you don't need to keep repeating `/somedir/` in all of your rules present in the same `.htaccess` file.

**How to get `RewriteBase` dynamically:**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(.*?/)(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=BASE:%1]
```

**About WP:**

Wordpress could safely remove the absolute path from the RewriteRule since they are using absolute path anyway. But the thing is that so many of WP plugins overwrite that .htaccess file so they just don't want to rely on presence of RewriteBase line.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm saying: given line #5 as in the question, line #1 is redundant.

Comment: And that is exactly I tried to explain in my answer (read till the last line where it can be useful).

Comment: I know, that's why I don't understand for what reason Wordpress always repeats the absolute path in the RewriteRule, the point is, there must be a reason for that.

Comment: There is no real advantage of not using `RewriteBase` and keep using `/somdir/` in all the rules. I have seen some cases where website owners want `RewriteBase` to be generated dynamically so that they don't need to change it from dev, staging OR live web servers with different paths.

Comment: I agree, and I'm starting to think that Wordpress could safely remove the absolute path from the RewriteRule, keeping the RewriteBase obviously.

Comment: Yes they can very well remove it since they are using absolute path anyway. But the thing is that so many of WP plugins overwrite that `.htaccess` file so they just don't want to rely on presence of `RewriteBase` line.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense! If you could please elaborate your answer to include your last explanation and specify that the redundancy is actually intentional for WP, I'll accept the answer.

Comment: Added some explanation.